# pandas dataframe select columns in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical, multi-index

I have the following pd.DataFrame:

```
Name    0                       1                      ...
Col     A           B           A            B         ...
0       0.409511    -0.537108   -0.355529    0.212134  ...
1       -0.332276   -1.087013    0.083684    0.529002  ...
2       1.138159    -0.327212    0.570834    2.337718  ...
```

It has MultiIndex columns with `names=['Name', 'Col']` and hierarchical levels. The `Name` label goes from 0 to n, and for each label, there are two `A` and `B` columns.

I would like to subselect all the `A` (or `B`) columns of this DataFrame.

Comment: This was introduced in 0.14.0: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindexing-using-slicers, ``df.loc[:,(slice(None),'A')]``

Answer (score 151, accepted):

There is a `get_level_values` method that you can use in conjunction with boolean indexing to get the the intended result.

```
In [13]:

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,4)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2],['A','B']])
print df
          1                   2          
          A         B         A         B
0  0.543980  0.628078  0.756941  0.698824
1  0.633005  0.089604  0.198510  0.783556
2  0.662391  0.541182  0.544060  0.059381
3  0.841242  0.634603  0.815334  0.848120
In [14]:

print df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='A']
          1         2
          A         A
0  0.543980  0.756941
1  0.633005  0.198510
2  0.662391  0.544060
3  0.841242  0.815334
```

Comment: Note that referring to the index level by name, `df.columns.get_level_values("Col")`, also seems to work, at least on Pandas 1.1.5.

Answer (score 67):

Method 1:

```
df.xs('A', level='Col', axis=1)
```

for more refer to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#cross-section

Method 2:

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'A')]
```

**Caveat:** this method requires the labels to be sorted. for more refer to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex

Comment: Is there a way to use the `.xs()` method with more than one column, say, columns `A` *and* `B`?

Comment: These solutions seem all overly complicated, there should be a more intuitive way to do this.

Comment: Note: `xs` cannot be used to set values. Slices have to be used for that.

Comment: @darXider According to the docstring, `df.xs( ('A', 'B'), ...)` is supposed to work.

Comment: @Seorendip: what is "overly complicated" in `df.xs('A', level='Col', axis=1)`? This call pretty much only gives the needed information and nothing else (I want the data with "Col" = "A", where you should look among the colum names), so I don't see how one could do better.

Answer (score 40):

EDIT*
Best way now is to use indexSlice for multi-index selections

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
A = df.loc[:,idx[:,'A']]
B = df.loc[:,idx[:,'B']]
```

Comment: Very elegant  method  thanks for this!