# How do I convert a flat DataFrame object to a DataFrame object with multiple column levels that is also grouped by a specific dimension?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert this:

```
          W         X         Y         Z       tdate tdim  stringdate
0  0.335737 -0.380237 -0.473996 -0.000448  2015-11-20    c  2015-11-20
1 -0.092511  1.149210 -0.834495 -0.585204  2015-05-25    c  2015-05-25
2  1.425946  1.293430 -0.545142  0.287451  2015-12-17    b  2015-12-17
3 -0.199412  1.011220  0.400355  0.470182  2015-03-21    c  2015-03-21
4  2.265234 -0.314174  0.684593 -1.360268  2015-12-23    b  2015-12-23
5 -0.192996  0.150177 -0.684978  0.464223  2015-11-19    b  2015-11-19
6 -1.089473 -1.375843 -0.901250 -0.775122  2015-07-25    c  2015-07-25
7 -0.572807 -2.484145 -2.339342 -0.263439  2015-05-31    a  2015-05-31
```

To this (with actual data instead of zero placeholder):

```
date    2015-11-20    2015-05-25    2015-12-17    2015-03-21    2015-12-23     \
metrics          W  X          W  X          W  X          W  X          W  X   
tdim                                                                            
a                0  0          0  0          0  0          0  0          0  0   
b                0  0          0  0          0  0          0  0          0  0   
c                0  0          0  0          0  0          0  0          0  0   

date    2015-11-19    2015-07-25    2015-05-31     
metrics          W  X          W  X          W  X  
tdim                                               
a                0  0          0  0          0  0  
b                0  0          0  0          0  0  
c                0  0          0  0          0  0
```

I've skimmed over [Pandas MultiIndexes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) and created one myself. That's how I arrived at the latter DataFrame, but I did not see an example in that documentation where he reindexes an existing DataFrame to have multiple column levels.

I have looked at this [Pandas: add a column to a multiindex column dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088741/pandas-add-a-column-to-a-multiindex-column-dataframe) and [pandas dataframe select columns in multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189575/pandas-dataframe-select-columns-in-multiindex). These are insightful but not specifically helpful for this case.

I have not attempted a brute force solution (i.e. manually populating data using loops).

I am using **Python 2.7.10** and **pandas 0.16.1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to use all `['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']` `columns`, and only one of the `date` columns. If so, the below should get you there - if you first apply `set_index` and then `unstack`, `pandas` creates the `MultiIndex` automatically, which you can then `swap` by `level` and `sort` as you wish:

```
df.columns.name = 'metrics'    
df = df.set_index(['tdate', 'tdim']).drop('stringdate', axis=1).unstack('tdate')
df = df.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

     tdate    11/19/15                                11/20/15                      \
metrics         W         X         Y         Z         W         X         Y   
tdim                                                                            
a             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
b       -0.192996  0.150177 -0.684978  0.464223       NaN       NaN       NaN   
c             NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.335737 -0.380237 -0.473996   

tdate             12/17/15             ...       5/25/15            5/31/15  \
metrics        Z         W        X    ...             Y        Z         W   
tdim                                   ...                                    
a            NaN       NaN      NaN    ...           NaN      NaN -0.572807   
b            NaN  1.425946  1.29343    ...           NaN      NaN       NaN   
c        -1/1/04       NaN      NaN    ...     -0.834495  -1/1/04       NaN   

tdate                                    7/25/15                                
metrics         X         Y          Z         W         X        Y          Z  
tdim                                                                            
a       -2.484145 -2.339342  -0.263439       NaN       NaN      NaN        NaN  
b             NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN        NaN  
c             NaN       NaN        NaN -1.089473 -1.375843 -0.90125  -0.775122
```

Comment: This works great. I obviously need to look into indexing DataFrame objects a bit more.