# Dictionary of dictionaries with iterables to pandas Dataframe with multiindex by index of iterables

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want a multi indexed pandas DataFrame from a dictionary of dictionaries. The inner dictionaries contain lists/numpy arrays of the same length.

```py
x = {'a': {'x': [0, 1, 2], 'y': [1 ,2 ,3]},
     'b': {'x': [4, 6, 8], 'y': [9, 8, 7]}}
some_function(x)
=>
          x      y  <- first index
      0 1 2  0 1 2  <- second index
    a 0 1 2  1 2 3
    b 4 6 8  9 8 7
```

This is what I already tried, but is there a more efficient way? Like only with pandas? Or is there a pandas function which can take care of that?

```
def dict_of_dicts_of_collections_to_multiindex_df(dict_of_dicts_of_collections):

    x = dict_of_dicts_of_collections

    result = {}

    for outer_key, intermediate_dict in x.items():
        result[outer_key] = {}

        for intermediate_key, collection in intermediate_dict.items():
            try:
                for i, e in enumerate(collection):
                    result[outer_key][(intermediate_key, i)] = e
            except TypeError:
                pass

    return pd.DataFrame(result).T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two alternative approaches to this problem, and timed the results. Also included the other answer as well as the original function.

```
from copy import deepcopy
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np


x = {'a': {'x': [0, 1, 2], 'y': [1 ,2 ,3]},
     'b': {'x': [4, 6, 8], 'y': [9, 8, 7]}}


test = deepcopy(x)
for i in range(1000):
    test.update({f'a_{i}':test['a']})

test2 = {k:{key: val*300 for key, val in v.items()} for k, v in x.items()}
print(len(test2['a']['x']))
for i in range(1000):
    test2.update({f'a_{i}':test2['a']})

def dict_of_dicts_of_collections_to_multiindex_df(dict_of_dicts_of_collections):
    x = dict_of_dicts_of_collections
    result = {}
    for outer_key, intermediate_dict in x.items():
        result[outer_key] = {}
        for intermediate_key, collection in intermediate_dict.items():
            try:
                for i, e in enumerate(collection):
                    result[outer_key][(intermediate_key, i)] = e
            except TypeError:
                pass
    return pd.DataFrame(result).T


def out_from_other_answer(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data).T    
    cols = df.columns
    df = pd.concat([df[col].apply(pd.Series) for col in cols], axis=1)
    #tweaked to  avoid hardcoding [0, 1, 2]
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cols, range(len(df.columns)//len(cols))])
    return df

def out2(dict_of_dicts):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_of_dicts.values()))
    out_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist())
                        for col in df.columns
                        ],
                        axis=1,
                        keys=df.columns,
                        )
    out_df.index = dict_of_dicts.keys()
    return out_df

def out3(data):
    temp = defaultdict(list)
    for d in list(data.values()):
        for k, v in d.items():
            temp[k].append(v)
    out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v) for v in temp.values()], axis=1, keys=temp.keys())
    out.index = data.keys()
    return out
```

Let us see the results.
With small data x.

```
%timeit dict_of_dicts_of_collections_to_multiindex_df(x)
%timeit out_from_other_answer(x)
%timeit out2(x)
%timeit out3(x)
1.63 ms ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
4.49 ms ± 492 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.44 ms ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.49 ms ± 98.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

With more rows but same columns test.

```
%timeit dict_of_dicts_of_collections_to_multiindex_df(test)
%timeit out_from_other_answer(test)
%timeit out2(test)
%timeit out3(test)
70.3 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
494 ms ± 40.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
4.81 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.37 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

With more rows and more columns, test2

```
%timeit dict_of_dicts_of_collections_to_multiindex_df(test2)
%timeit out_from_other_answer(test2)
%timeit out2(test2)
%timeit out3(test2)
1.24 s ± 19.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.1 s ± 63.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
590 ms ± 39.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
598 ms ± 44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It seems each solution is affected differently in terms of what dimension of data increases. Overall it seems that out3 is the best bet. Essentially, it's best to change the layout of input data before working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider to play with some reverse engineering? What I mean is to build a multiindex dataframe and check what it looks like when you `print(df.to_dict())` Using the first part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25190070/4819376) we can have an output as your desired one,

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [[0, 1, 2, 1 ,2 ,3],
        [4, 6, 8, 9, 8, 7]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.colums =  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x','y'], [0,1,2]])
df.index = ['a', 'b']

print(df.to_dict())

{('x', 0): {'a': 0, 'b': 4},
 ('x', 1): {'a': 1, 'b': 6},
 ('x', 2): {'a': 2, 'b': 8},
 ('y', 0): {'a': 1, 'b': 9},
 ('y', 1): {'a': 2, 'b': 8},
 ('y', 2): {'a': 3, 'b': 7}}
```

So if you can have your data as two lists you could use the `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` trick.

Otherwise

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'a': {'x': [0, 1, 2], 'y': [1 ,2 ,3]},
        'b': {'x': [4, 6, 8], 'y': [9, 8, 7]}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

# you obeserve that expand list to columns
df["x"].apply(pd.Series)

# then using this for every column
# and again pd.MultiIndex.from_product
# gives you the desired output
cols = df.columns
df = pd.concat([df[col].apply(pd.Series) for col in cols], axis=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cols, [0,1,2]])
```