# Not able to get data, downloaded in group by format using package yfinance, into pandas dataframe only for specific tickers in my sub list

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I am downloading data using python package yfinance and below is the code I am using for this:

```
# pip install yfinance

import yfinance as yf

# list of tickers for which data is to be downloaded
myLst = ['TSLA', 'MSFT', 'FB', 'IBM', 'AAPL', 'WFC', 'BAC', 'INTC', 'PRLAX', 'QASGX', 'HISFX']

# from which date?
start_date = '2018-01-01'

# to which date?
end_date = '2019-12-31'

# download the data
mydf = yf.download(myLst, start = start_date, end = end_date, group_by = "ticker")
```

This returns me the data in a dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

But I am not able to get this data into a dataframe like this:

[image]

Although I tried something like this :

```
assets = ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'FB']

assetsDF = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['Close'] for x in mydf[a]['Close']} for a in assets
})
```

But I know I am not correct here. Is there any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas column multi-index to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106554/pandas-column-multi-index-to-rows)

Comment: That was to link to other questions that are similar. See Linked and Related on the right side of the screen

Comment: You will probably find [How to deal with multi-level column names downloaded with yfinance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107594) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered here: [pandas dataframe select columns in multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189575/pandas-dataframe-select-columns-in-multiindex)

```
mydf.iloc[:, mydf.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Close']
```

@EDIT: remove useless column level

```
mydf.columns = mydf.columns.droplevel(1)
```

Comment: thanks so much @ct30 , but this still does not  return the required format. why there is one more row 'Close'? What I am looking is col headers with just date and names of the tickers in assets list. :)